# How to use ViewModel with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am trying to use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel) with Jetpack Compose by doing a number increment.

It's not working. Maybe I'm not using the ViewModel in the right way.

Here is my Activity code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Greeting()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(
    helloViewModel: ViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(
            text = helloViewModel.number.toString(),
            fontSize = 60.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
        Button(onClick = { helloViewModel.addNumber() }) {
            Text(text = "Increment Number ${helloViewModel.number}")
        }

    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    AppTheme {
        Greeting()
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel code:

```
class ViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var number : Int = 0
    fun addNumber(){
        number++
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your [Composable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/Composable) will not pick up the changes in the `ViewModel.number` value unless the value is contained within a [State](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/State) object. You can wrap the value in a mutable [State](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/State) property with [mutableStateOf()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateOf(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutationPolicy)) or [mutableIntStateOf()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableIntStateOf(kotlin.Int)), as follows:

```
class ViewModel: ViewModel() {
    var number : Int by mutableIntStateOf(0)
        private set

    fun addNumber(){
        number++
    }
}
```

Or you can declare the property as a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData) or [Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/) and then reference the value as a [State](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/State) object in your [Composable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/Composable) with the [LiveData.observeAsState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/livedata/package-summary#(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData).observeAsState()) or [Flow.collectAsState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).collectAsState(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)) extension function.

I suggest you start with the [State and Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) documentation and the [Jetpack Compose: State](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mymWGMy9pYI) YouTube video. These two resources explain the basic principles.

Comment: hey @PhilDukhov I am seeing your answer and little bit confused. Can you please guide me on you used `private set` below the  `number ` attribute. So what the use of that ?

Comment: @vivekmodi it's useful to make sure this variable is only modifiable by the view model itself - often `addNumber` will contain more logic than just updating the value, and restricting modification scope is a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

I use Hilt along with ViewModel. Here is another way of using it

```
@Composable
fun PokemonListScreen(
    navController: NavController
) {

    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<PokemonListVm>()
    val lazyPokemonItems: LazyPagingItems<PokedexListEntry> = viewModel.pokemonList.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

}
```

I use this composable instead of a fragment and I keep one reference to the composable in the parent