# Jetpack Compose how to remove focused TextField inside LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I have a `LazyColumn` with Text field and button to toggle is the text field available or not.

```kotlin
LazyColumn() {
    item {
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello") }
        if (myViewModel.showTextField.value) {
            TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
        }
        TextButton(onClick = { myViewModel.toggleField() }) {
            Text(text = "toggle")
        }
    }
}
```

And viewModel has code like this

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _showTextField = mutableStateOf(true)
    val showTextField : State<Boolean> = _showTextField

    fun toggleField() {
        _showTextField.value = !showTextField.value
    }
}
```

And now when I click on TextField before clicking toggle button. So `TextField` has focus before removing it, the application crashes with following error:

```
2022-04-09 19:43:03.417 12336-12336/com.courtesy.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.courtesy.test, PID: 12336
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: LayoutCoordinates androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifierLocalConsumerNode@bab1d96 is not attached!
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.localBoundingBoxOf(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:714)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.ContentInViewModifier.onSizeChanged-O0kMr_c(Scrollable.kt:524)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.ContentInViewModifier.onRemeasured-ozmzZPI(Scrollable.kt:492)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$onMeasured$invokeRemeasureCallbacks$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:244)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$onMeasured$invokeRemeasureCallbacks$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:242)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.withNoObservations(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:55)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.onMeasured(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:247)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:405)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:40)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$performMeasure$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:1342)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$performMeasure$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:1341)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1918)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:121)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.performMeasure-BRTryo0$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1341)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1295)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1291)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-sdFAvZA(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:180)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:256)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:36)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:201)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:756)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.internalOnMeasure$ui_release(ComposeView.android.kt:298)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:285)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
2022-04-09 19:43:03.418 12336-12336/com.courtesy.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-04-09 19:43:03.816 12336-12336/com.courtesy.test I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12336 SIG: 9
```

It works fine when I don't click the `TextField` before clicking the button.

And also everything works correctly if I use `Column` instead of `LazyColumn`.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: You seems to be using two different view models? `myViewModel` and `todoViewModel`? After replacing the second one with the first one, I can't reproduce the crash, both on Compose **1.1.1** and **1.2.0-alpha07**.

Comment: p.s. check out a shorter version of private set compose variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69742362/3585796)

Comment: It should be same viewModel in both places, fixed the example code. But since you mentioned you used 1.2.0-alpha07. I doubled check I used 1.2.0-alpha06 and yes in 1.2.0-alpha07 it seems to be working. So thanks for your help problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by changing compose version from **1.2.0-alpha06** to **1.2.0-alpha07**