# Best practice when using mutableState with jetpack compose inside viewmodel with exposing mutable state

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I have the following ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class ShareViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val taskRepository: TaskRepository
): ViewModel() {

    private val searchAppBarStateMutableState: MutableState<SearchAppBarState> = mutableStateOf(SearchAppBarState.CLOSED)
    val searchAppBarState: State<SearchAppBarState> = searchAppBarStateMutableState

    private val listOfTaskMutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<TodoTaskEntity>>(emptyList())
    val listOfTaskStateFlow = listOfTaskMutableStateFlow.asStateFlow()
}
```

I never expose mutableStateFlow as in the example above. And SonarLint will show a warning when doing this.

```
MutableStateFlow" and "MutableSharedFlow" should not be exposed
```

So I apply the same technique to the `mutableState`

However, If I do like this below, I don't get any warning.

```
val searchAppBarStateMutableState: MutableState<SearchAppBarState> = mutableStateOf(SearchAppBarState.CLOSED)
```

Just wondering what is the best practice for using MutableState with jetpack compose.

Comment: A common practice is to expose read-only states from viewmodels because you want to avoid the view modifying the state directly. I'd follow the same guideline with Compose.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71817269/15880865

Comment: The shortest version for mutable state is using delegation with private setter, like showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69742362/3585796). `: State<SearchAppBarState>` is also a possible variant if you need to pass a state for some reason. Not sure why your linter is not happy, the flow variant seems fine too.

Comment: Could it be that settings private variables need to have an underscore in front, "    private val _listOfTaskMutableStateFlow.". Other than that seems all fine in regards to the lint issue.

https://rules.sonarsource.com/kotlin/RSPEC-6305

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use mutableState with viewmodel, define mutableState with private setter inside viewmodel, ex -

```
var isVisible by mutableState(false)
    private set
```

By doing above we can read the mutable state from outside of viewmodel but not update it. To update create a public function inside viewmodel, ex -

```
fun setVisibility(value: Boolean) {
    isVisible = value
}
```

By making a setter function we are following separation of concerns and having a single source of truth for editing the mutableState.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error  is in that you are setting

```
    val searchAppBarState: State<SearchAppBarState> = searchAppBarStateMutableState
```

if you want to share private value as not mutable you shouldn't set it equal rather you can use get modifier

```
    val searchAppBarState: State<SearchAppBarState> get() = searchAppBarStateMutableState
```

Also it would be better to name it with underscore as many developers are used to like:

```
    private val _searchAppBarState: MutableState<SearchAppBarState> = mutableStateOf(SearchAppBarState.CLOSED)
    val searchAppBarState: State<SearchAppBarState> get() = _searchAppBarState
```